# What's happening here? Dialect

Tags: spelling

I recently found this [(https://obst-bilder.de/)](https://obst-bilder.de/) website.

Is this a dialect? Who speaks like this? And where? I found some similarities, for example

> Dua Physalis gahürt zor Gettomg Jodam

looks like

> Der -- gehört zur --

What's going on here? I already asked a friend over WhatsApp, and he didn't know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Honestly I am pretty sure this is some kind of SEO (Search Engine Optimization) test website and the words are just some kind of hardly understandable gibberish. Take a look at the author, google him and you will find other sites about vegetables, etc.

I think Ingo (the author of the website) wants to find out how Google's image search engine works and how to get first place.

You can also find his (Test-)Blog with some statistics.

**edit (some analysis):**

It is noticeable that he always only correctly writes one word. It can therefore be assumed that each page was optimized for just this word. In this case the name of the fruit, or the word "Obst" itself. On the main page it is also striking how he tries to imitate compound words (Obstpeo, Staumobst). Just to create a text that looks like natural German and to fool Google's search algorithm.

**edit 2 (the algorithm):**

Just for fun. This is what he did:

Actually he twisted some letters. Pseudocode:

```
Ignore charsequence x (e.g. Obst)
for every other char do
a <-> e
b <-> p
i <-> o
m <-> n
w <-> v
ä <-> ü
ö -> ä
```

So this is the first paragraph (case-insensitive):

> obst, die essbaren, meist saftreichen, fleischigen früchte bzw. die samenkerne von kultursorten v.a. mehrjähriger obstgehölze. im obstbau und obsthandel unterscheidet man: kernobst (z.b. apfel, birne), steinobst (z.b. kirsche, aprikose), schalenobst (z.b. hasel- und walnuss) und beerenobst (z.b. heidelbeere, johannisbeere).

I think this was made by a word scrambler. But it's a no brainer to program it yourself in 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Sounds sound ...

Comment: Oh! Thank you. Are the sentences sentences?

Comment: yes, it is a sentence. Unscrambled it would read, "Die [Physalis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasenkirschen) gehört zur Gattung Juden[kirschen]". If it was not for this answer, we might have guessed that there is somewhere a very remote valley in Switzerland or Bavaria, where ... oh I'm so trying this on my coworkers now.

Comment: In the Datenschutzerklärung (privacy policy) the owner explains "Ich betreibe diese Website seit Dezember 2013 als Testseite für die Google-Bildersuche." (roughly translates to) "I run this website since December 2013 as a test page for Google's image search"

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be an attempt to reverse-engineer (and analyze) Google's image search algorithm for marketing purposes (note here is another site gemuese-bilder.de that seems to do the same).

Google image search seems to ignore graphics-only sites, so they had to add some text that might pass a language test for German, but had to be complete rubbish in order to filter for a graphics-only search.